# Effect of treatment on the treated using the graph

Tags: self-study, causality, graphical-model, causal-diagram

From the diagram, I need to find the effect of education on those students whose salary is $Y=1$.
I was given the hint to use $E[Y_1 − Y_0|Y = 1]$.

**My attempt:**

I tried to expand the above equation and got as follows:

$E[Y_1 − Y_0|Y = 1] = E[Y|Y=1]-t(0-E[X|Y=1])$

After this I'm stuck and need help to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I see you are studying Pearl's *Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer*, co-written with Glymour and Jewell. Excellent choice!

Theorem 4.3.2 says that if $\tau$ is
the total effect of $X$ on $Y$, which is $ab$ in this case, then, for any evidence $Z=e,$ we
have
$$E[Y_{X=x}|Z=e]=E[Y|Z=e]+\tau(x-E[X|Z=e]).$$
So, in our case, if we want to compute $E[Y_1-Y_0|Y=1],$ we must evaluate
\begin{align*}
E[Y_1-Y_0|Y=1]
&=E[Y|Z=e]+ab(1-E[X|Z=e])-E[Y|Z=e]-ab(0-E[X|Z=e])\\
&=E[Y|Y=1]+ab(1-E[X|Y=1])-E[Y|Y=1]+abE[X|Y=1]\\
&=1+ab-abE[X|Y=1]-1+abE[X|Y=1].
\end{align*}
Can you finish?